# How to read percentage as decimal number?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find the decimal value from a percentage that a user inputs.

For example, if a user inputs "15", i will need to do a calculation of `0.15 * number`.

I've tried using `.to_f`, but it returns `15.0`:

```
15.to_f
#=> 15.0
```

I also tried to add `0.` to the beginning of the percentage, but it just returns `0`:

```
15.to_s.rjust(4, "0.").to_i
#=> 0
```

Comment: The right approach depends on what you are trying to achieve. Why do you want to turn `15` into `0.15`?

Comment: im trying to find the amount from a percentage that a user inputs. For example if a user input "15", i will need to do a calculation of `0.15 * number` @Stefan

Comment: Do you want the result to be a string? A float? A big decimal? It's not clear what you are looking for. From your example code, it looks like you are looking for an integer, i.e. a whole number, but in that case, the answer is easy: *any* number prepended with `0.` as an integer will *always* be `0`.

Comment: From your comment it appears that you wish to "convert the string representation of an integer that is between 0 and 100 to the string representation of the corresponding percentage (without the character '%')". Regardless, you need to edit to clarify your question. If you obtain the string using `gets` is will of course end with a line terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to find the amount from a percentage that a user inputs

If you retrieve the input via `gets`, you typically convert it to a numeric value first, e.g.

```
percentage = gets.to_i
#=> 15
```

Ruby is not aware that this `15` is a percentage. And since there's no `Percentage` class, you have to convert it into one of the existing numeric classes.

15% is equal to the [fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction) 15/100, the [ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio) 15:100, or the [decimal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) 0.15.

If you want the number as a (maybe inexact) [`Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Float.html), you can divide it by `100` via [`fdiv`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Integer.html#fdiv-method):

```
15.fdiv(100)
#=> 0.15
```

If you prefer a [`Rational`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Rational.html) you can use [`quo`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Numeric.html#quo-method): (it might also return an `Integer`)

```
15.quo(100)
#=> (3/20)
```

Or maybe [`BigDecimal`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) for an arbitrary-precision decimal number:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

BigDecimal(15) / 100
#=> 0.15e0
```

`BigDecimal` also accepts strings, so you could pass the input without prior conversion:

```
input = gets
BigDecimal(input) / 100
#=> 0.15e0
```

Comment: or ... as  a String :

Comment: @CarySwoveland strings are underrates, but the `0.15 * number` part the OP mentioned in the comments could be tough :-)

Comment: I think I've established a mindmeld with the OP, but let's wait and see the answer to my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Divide by `100.0`

The easiest way to do what you're trying to do is to divide your input value by a [Float](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Float.html) (keeping in mind the inherent inaccuracy of floating point values). For example:

```
percentage = 15
percentage / 100.0
#=> 0.15
```

One benefit of this approach (among others) is that it can handle fractional percentages just as easily. Consider:

```
percentage = 15.6
percentage / 100.0
#=> 0.156
```

If floating point precision isn't sufficient for your use case, then you should consider using [Rational](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Rational.html) or [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) numbers instead of a Float. Your mileage will very much depend on your semantic intent and accuracy requirements.

#### Caveats

Make sure you have ahold of a valid Integer in the first place. While others might steer you towards [String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-to_i), a more robust validation is to use [Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) so that an exception will be raised if the value can't be coerced into a valid Integer. For example:

```
print "Enter integer: "
percentage = Integer gets
```

If you enter `15\n` then:

```
percentage.class
#=> Integer
```

If you enter something that can't be coerced to an Integer, like `foo\n`, then:

```
ArgumentError (invalid value for Integer(): "foo\n")
```

Using [String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) is much more permissive, and can return `0` when you aren't expecting it, such as when called on nil, an empty string, or alphanumeric values that don't start with an integer. It has other interesting edge cases as well, so it's not always the best option for validating input.

Comment: _"While others might steer you towards String#to_i"_ made my day  You might want to call `Float(gets)` instead for the aforementioned "fractional percentages".

Comment: Dividing by 100 is *not at all* the same thing as prepending `0.`. This will only work if the input is between 10 and 99.

Comment: @Stefan Agreed. I stuck with `Integer(gets)` simply because the OP seems to be expecting an Integer rather than a Float, and I wanted to stick as closely as I could to his use case without seeing the entire context of his code. You're definitely right that `Float(gets)` could shave a step if Float is the right internal representation for the user's input.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Prepending a String is suboptimal, too. `0.15.6` is unlikely to be the expected (or valid) output. There are always edge cases in any code path, which is why I raised the issue of validating input values in the first place. No matter what you do, casting a value will require some sort of validation of input and output values.

Comment: What I meant is that the OP wants to prepend `0.`, which would mean that `5` gets converted to `0.5` and `123456789` gets converted to `0.123456789`. Your results would, however, be `0.05` (off by an order of magnitude) and `123456.789` (off by 6 orders of magnitude).

Comment: @JörgWMittag I see your point. However, the expectation defined in the original post is that the user is entering a percentage as an integer (even though `gets` obviously returns a string). So, in this case, I'd expect an input of `5` to result in `0.05` rather than `0.5`.  `1_000` would yield `10.0`, which is also right, although it doesn't handle commas as separators. It's all about expectations, though, so other answers that handle more unexpected inputs or provide greater precision may be preferable for future visitors.

Comment: _"the OP wants to prepend 0."_ – although the question is phrased that way, I don't think this is what the OP actually wants :-)